# How to run a shell command from Grunt task function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to move some icons in my app directory based on a function i have inside my `Gruntfile.js`. Would it be possible to do something like this? I've tried the following (going into dev or staging folder and copying all files to the previous directory), but coudn't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
grunt.registerTask('setAppIcon', 'Task that sets the app icon', function(environment) {
    if (environment.toLowerCase() == "development") {

        grunt.task.run(['exec:command:cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/dev && cp -a . ../']);

    } else if (environment.toLowerCase() == "staging") {

        grunt.task.run(['exec:command:cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/staging && cp -a . ../']);

    } 
});
```

Comment: What you get when you run that task? I have not used grunt from years, but I don't remember that syntax for running shell commands. When I tried to run that command I got "Warning: Task "exec:command:cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/dev && cp -a . ../" not found." message.

I think you should use dedicated grunt package for running shell commands. Maybe https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell

Comment: Thanks Dawid, i ended up using shelljs but i tried your solution nonetheless and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to achieve your requirement, however, when you invoke the  [grunt.task.run](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run) command inside your function (i.e. custom task)  you need to provide a reference to a task to run.

If you define a separate [Target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets), *(Let's call call them `copy_dev` and `copy_staging` - as shown in the example below)*, for each `cd ... && cp ...`  command in the [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) Task it should work successfully.

---

**Gruntfile.js**

The following `Gruntfile.js` gist shows how this can be achieved:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

  grunt.initConfig({
    exec: {
      copy_dev: {
        cmd: 'cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/dev && cp -a . ../'
      },
      copy_staging: {
        cmd: 'cd app/lib/extras/res/icon/ios/staging && cp -a . ../'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('setAppIcon', 'Task that sets the app icon', function() {
    var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

    // Exit early if NODE_ENV variable has not been set.
    if (!environment) {
      grunt.log.writeln(
        '\"setAppIcon\"" task failed - NODE_ENV has not been set.'['yellow']
      )
      return
    }

    if (environment.toLowerCase() == "development") {
      grunt.task.run('exec:copy_dev');
      grunt.log.writeln('>> Copying icons from \"dev\"...')
    } else if (environment.toLowerCase() == "staging") {
      grunt.task.run('exec:copy_staging');
      grunt.log.writeln('>> Copying icons from \"staging\"...')
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'setAppIcon' ]);
};
```

---

**Additional notes**

Inside the custom task/function named `setAppIcon` we obtain the current node environment using nodes builtin [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)

When running `$ grunt` via your CLI *(using the gist shown above)*, and assuming your `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable has not been set, or it has possibly been unset by running `$ unset NODE_ENV`, you will see the following message:

> `"setAppIcon"" task failed - NODE_ENV has not been set.`

However, if the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable has been set to either `development` or `staging` the files will be copied as expected.

For example running either of the following via your CLI will work successfully:

`$ export NODE_ENV=development && grunt`

or

`$ export NODE_ENV=staging && grunt`

You will also see either of the following messages logged to the console:

> `>> Copying icons from "dev"...`

or

> `>> Copying icons from "staging"...`

After `process.env.NODE_ENV` has been set to either `development` or `staging` then just running `$ grunt` via your CLI, will copy files according to which environment is set.

Comment: Although the answer above utilizes [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec), you could also use [grunt-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-shell) instead.